# Visual Studio 2012 Performance Profiler not pointing to the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm testing the performance of my C# application on Visual Studio 2012.
I used the Release build mode and opened the Performance Wizard on my application, but the performance Hot Paths is pointing to the System dlls (atidxx32.dll) but not to the code of my application.

Are they any specific steps that I need to do so that the profiler will look into the performance of my web application and not the system?

Comment: Hmm, that's unmanaged code.  A video driver DLL no less, that ought not ever show up when you profile a web app.  Sounds to me that you are actually profiling the browser :)  Follow this basic [how-to MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx) to have a shot at getting it right.

Comment: Just to add to what Hans said: Is this a web-application (e.g. ASP.NET) by any chance? If so, you will need to profile the server side process (e.g. iisexpress.exe, w3wp.exe), not the browser :)

Answer (score 0):

I did some researches and found that the Web configurations of my ASP.NET web application are set to use Visual Studio Development Server and not IIS Express.
I changed the configuration and all went very well, the Sampling mode of the performance profiler is now profiling my application properly.

Go to Proprieties of the web application project / Web / Servers, tick Use IIS Express.